# PayPal integration (MECL)

Tags: android, paypal

I just want payment methods to my application. I just surfing for that. I got [X Developer](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk#6) as best to do for Payment methods in Android.

From, this blog i got the Jar files and one Example. In that example, They've integrate onewebView for pay the money through `Checkout with Paypal` button. I need to know. What they're done with that.

In my application, i've one button like `Pay` When i press that button, i want to redirect this page, with my payment details --

[image: Paypal]

I don't know how they redirect to this page. Can anyone done this means, please, explain me what are all the important for the payment in Android through `MECL`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly redirect to here by clicking your pay button.
If you want to open this screen you must have to click on the *`Pay with Paypal`* button of the Paypal.

There are certain checks that paypal is doing on the click of *`Pay with Paypal`* button.
For example if once you click on the paypal button and do your work on paypal and comes back to your screen and if you again try to click on the  *`Pay with Paypal button`* it will not work.

In short  *`Pay with Paypal button`* is the entry point for the paypal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pay with PayPal. MECL and MPL. You should try using MPL first since it is easier. Here is a good tutorial on how to implement MPL in your android application.

http://vivdub.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-paypal-integration-part-1.html

If you really want to use MECL then there is a Pizza APP example that comes with the library that implements it. You should take a look.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I've done already `MPL` after finishing `MPL` only i just started to do the `MECL` Now, i've done both of them.

Comment: hi praveen , will you please share sample code with MPL.